# Comparing two objects with Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there an easy utility with Groovy that will give me a difference of two different objects? I'm getting the message via the equals method that they aren't equal but where can I find what properties are not being matched?

Comment: Objects are matched via their hashCode and equals methods, not by an exhaustive comparison of properties

Comment: I understand that, however, they do not tell you what property failed to match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that this was easy to do as that the .properties attribute of the object produced a map listing the property name as the key and the value as the value.

Once I had that then I could do a difference between the two maps and I've got the answer I was looking for.

Each of the objects has a .properties extension. This works like the Python .dict.

**Example**

```
object1.properties - object2.properties
```

So these will show you the difference between the object1 properties and object2 properties, but only where there exist an entity (key+value) that differs from within object2. If there are extra properties in object2 they will not be shown.

Comment: how about adding your code as an example for others?

Comment: Done. (More characters needed, please disreguard this needless text)

Comment: As long as the object can be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap. As always it depends on how your object was implemented